# How to make user package folders work in repl.it?

Tags: java

I am a college student learning Java and our instructor makes us present our work to the class using the repl.it online IDE. I successfully coded the project in JetBrains IDEAJ on my desktop and it works perfectly but when I went to port it into repl.it it will not compile. The problem appears to be that repl.it allows multiple files and folders but there is something about `package` and `import` statements that it does not handle normally. I even named the entry class as **Main.java** per repl.it standards in anticipation of the need to port it over so that is not the issue.

Here is an outline of my package:

> **Class Hierarchy**
>   `java.lang.Object`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.Clock` (*implements `mambrose.clockproject.Clock_Interface`*)
>   `mambrose.clockproject.DigitalClock`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.WristWatch`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.MechanicalClock`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.CuckooClock`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.GrandfatherClock`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.NaturalClock`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.SundialClock`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.QuantumClock`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.AtomicClock`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.ClocksSimulation`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.ClockTime`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.Main`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.TimesConverter` (*implements `mambrose.clockproject.Time_Constants`*)
>   **Interface Hierarchy**
>   `mambrose.clockproject.Clock_Interface`
>   `mambrose.clockproject.Time_Constants`
>   **Enum Hierarchy**
>   `java.lang.Object`
>   `java.lang.Enum<E>` (*implements `java.lang.Comparable<T>`,  `java.io.Serializable`*)
>   `mambrose.clockproject.Clock_Interface.CLOCK_TYPE`

As you can see it is a little complicated but here are the 2 key points:

1. class Main contains method main() -- per repl.it standards/requirements
2. main() calls ClocksSimulation.run() which instantiates various objects and sends them messages (class methods) to do things.

Naturally each of these files contains the first line of:
 `package mambrose.clocksproject;` 
and a number of them also contain the statement:
 `import static mambrose.clockproject.Clock_Interface.CLOCK_TYPE.*;`

I have tried the following:

1. Uploaded my sourcecode folders as:
   **`mambrose`**->**`clockproject`**->*`all the .java files`*
   Will not compile. repl.it default Main.java is empty so `main()` not found.
2. Copied (overwrote) *my* Main.java onto the Main.java in the repl.it default directory.
   Will not compile. Complains of multiple `main()` methods.
3. Deleted the Main.java inside the subfolder.
   Again error says main() not found.
4. Tried moving everything into the top level directory and removing all the package statements. Adjusted the import statements to read: `import static Clock_Interface.CLOCK_TYPE.*;`
   Will not compile, says:

   > package Clock_Interface does not exist.

Does anybody know how to make repl.it get package and import statements to work?

Comment: Seems like this would be a better question for your professor or the folks at repl.it

Comment: @MikeTheLiar I did ask at REPL.IT but their forums are very quiet. I won't see my professor until Thursday night and the first thing he will ask (he always does) is "What have you done to try and solve this before coming to me?" (and you guys are on his list of recommended resources). I'm guessing this is a programming/syntax issue since REPL.IT has no substantial user options that I can detect.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use import and package keywords, we need either Maven or Gradle tool, which is not available on Repl. So, the answer is, you cannot do it.

Found the answer on their community [forum](https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-to-import-packages-in-java/14232#Answer%20accepted).

Comment: **First**, the answer about needing Maven or Gradle was wrong because those are only _needed_ when importing _compiled outside libraries_ such as shown in the above [forum article](https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-to-import-packages-in-java/14232#Answer%20accepted), not for importing _local source code_ files. Keywords **package** and **import** were part of JAVA long before Maven or Gradle existed. **Second**, long after the above answer was written, REPL.IT added support for Maven & Gradle (see comments in the same forum article) so this answer is also incorrect by virtue of being obsolete.